# TQFTs and Feynman motives

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, topological-field-theory, non-commutative-geometry, algebraic-geometry

*Questions*
Is a topological quantum field theory metrizable? Or else a TQFT coming from a subfactor?
For a given metric, are there always renormalization and Feynman diagrams?
Is there always a Feynman motive related to the theory?
Finally, does this Feynman motive depend on the choice of the metric?

*Motivations*
My motivations come from the observation that the subfactors theory and the motives theory are both an "enriched Galois theory" so that I asked myself if there is a link between these two enrichment.
The path through TQFTs and Feynman motives *could* be a link.
All these questions *could* be unified by "Is the Feynman motive a topological invariant?".

*References*
 - Y. André; [An Introduction to Motives (Pure motives, mixed motives, periods)](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/PanoramasSyntheses/2004/17/html/smf_pano-synth_17.php); 2004
 -  P. Cartier; [A mad day's work: from Grothendieck to Connes and Kontsevich, the evolution of concepts of space and symmetry](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2001-38-04/S0273-0979-01-00913-2/S0273-0979-01-00913-2.pdf);  2001.
 -  A. Connes, D. Kreimer; [Renormalization in quantum field theory and the Riemann-Hilbert problem I](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9912092) and [II](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0003188);  2000, 2001.
 -  A. Connes, M. Marcolli; [Noncommutative Geometry, Quantum Field Theory and Motives](http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/bookwebfinal.pdf);  2008.
 -  S. Henry;  [From toposes to non-commutative geometry through the study of internal Hilbert spaces](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~simon.henry/Thesis.pdf); PhD dissertation;  2014.
 - V. Kodiyalam, V.S. Sunder; [Topological quantum field theories from subfactors](http://books.google.fr/books?id=2gQBbYHqIeQC&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=topological%20quantum%20field%20theories%20from%20subfactors&source=bl&ots=_gGwfHNvGt&sig=w_YDBTL8JgD5Oj6gqtQXinNSd0g&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=dPU1U4nGA-HT0QXLqYGgAg&ved=0CIABEOgBMAY#v=onepage&q&f=false);    2000.
 - V. Kodiyalam, V. Pati, V.S. Sunder; [Subfactors and 1+1-dimensional TQFTs](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507050);  2005.
 - M. Marcolli; [Feynman motives](http://books.google.fr/books?id=HJ5clJKW9L0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr);  2010.

Comment: Please define acronyms upon first use.  Here, in the subject.

Comment: @garyp: see the (original) long version on mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/q/161641/34538

Comment: ... ok, but how does that help?

Comment: @garyp: all the background is there, and all the concepts (subfactor, planar algebra, tqft, topos, motive) have a link to their definition.

Comment: Yes, but what we need here is a definition of TQFT in the subject so that people who should skip the post will know without having to read it.

Comment: @garyp: ok I see. TQFT = [Topological Quantum Field Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_quantum_field_theory).

Comment: It is very unclear indeed what is being asked in this question and there is no obvious way to answer it. I am surprised it has not been closed and more surprised it is upvoted.